# How do I validate that has_one association exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models `Person` and `Address`:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address
end
```

```rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
end
```

How do I validate that each points to the other?

I want to do something similar to:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address
    validates :address, presence: true
end
```

Of course this doesn't work because `address` is not an attribute on `Person`.

What is the correct way in Rails to ensure that a record has a valid association with another record?

Comment: Does `has_one :address, required: true` do anything for you?

Comment: Do you want to check that associated address is valid or check that person always has an address?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address, required: true
end
```

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
end
```

See the `required` option in the options section of https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

`belongs_to` in Rails 5 is now automatically required so you don't need to put anything different inside of `Address.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `validates_associated :address` to validate associations